Unable to link libcurl statically and other libraries dynamically
I'm trying tu use curl-config --static-libs which is supposed to link libcurl statically but link all of libcurl's own dependencies dynamically.
This is all in a current ubuntu noble container
root@74c0362a3530:/# curl-config --static-libs
-Wl,-Bstatic -lcurl -Wl,-Bdynamic -lnghttp2 -lidn2 -lrtmp -lssh -lssh -lpsl -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -llber -lldap -llber -lzstd -lbrotlidec -lz
root@74c0362a3530:/# gcc -o main main.c $(curl-config --static-libs)
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnghttp2: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lidn2: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrtmp: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssh: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssh: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpsl: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgssapi_krb5: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llber: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lldap: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llber: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lzstd: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbrotlidec: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz: No such file or directory

My guess is that the linker tries to also link these libraries statically, because if we look at what curl is linked against, all libraries resolve.
root@74c0362a3530:/# ldd /usr/bin/curl
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffffb1add000)
        libcurl.so.4 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x0000ffffb1970000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x0000ffffb1930000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffffb1770000)
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffffb1aa0000)
        libnghttp2.so.14 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x0000ffffb1720000)
        libidn2.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x0000ffffb16e0000)
        librtmp.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x0000ffffb16a0000)
        libssh.so.4 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4 (0x0000ffffb1610000)
        libpsl.so.5 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x0000ffffb15d0000)
        libssl.so.3 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x0000ffffb1500000)
        libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x0000ffffb1080000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x0000ffffb1010000)
        libldap.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libldap.so.2 (0x0000ffffb0f90000)
        liblber.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liblber.so.2 (0x0000ffffb0f60000)
        libzstd.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x0000ffffb0ea0000)
        libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x0000ffffb0e70000)
        libunistring.so.5 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.5 (0x0000ffffb0ca0000)
        libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x0000ffffb0a80000)
        libhogweed.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 (0x0000ffffb0a10000)
        libnettle.so.8 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 (0x0000ffffb09a0000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x0000ffffb0900000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0000ffffb0820000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0000ffffb07d0000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000ffffb07a0000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x0000ffffb0770000)
        libsasl2.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x0000ffffb0730000)
        libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x0000ffffb06f0000)
        libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x0000ffffb0520000)
        libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x0000ffffb04e0000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x0000ffffb04b0000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000ffffb0480000)
        libffi.so.8 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x0000ffffb0450000)

Linking dynamically works
root@74c0362a3530:/# curl-config --libs
-lcurl
root@74c0362a3530:/# cc -o main main.c $(curl-config --libs)
root@74c0362a3530:/# ldd main
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000ffffa070d000)
        libcurl.so.4 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x0000ffffa05d0000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000ffffa0410000)
        libnghttp2.so.14 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14 (0x0000ffffa03c0000)
        libidn2.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x0000ffffa0380000)
        librtmp.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x0000ffffa0340000)
        libssh.so.4 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4 (0x0000ffffa02b0000)
        libpsl.so.5 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x0000ffffa0270000)
        libssl.so.3 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 (0x0000ffffa01a0000)
        libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x0000ffff9fd20000)
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x0000ffff9fcb0000)
        libldap.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libldap.so.2 (0x0000ffff9fc30000)
        liblber.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liblber.so.2 (0x0000ffff9fc00000)
        libzstd.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x0000ffff9fb40000)
        libbrotlidec.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1 (0x0000ffff9fb10000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x0000ffff9fad0000)
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000ffffa06d0000)
        libunistring.so.5 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.5 (0x0000ffff9f900000)
        libgnutls.so.30 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x0000ffff9f6e0000)
        libhogweed.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 (0x0000ffff9f670000)
        libnettle.so.8 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 (0x0000ffff9f600000)
        libgmp.so.10 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x0000ffff9f560000)
        libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0000ffff9f480000)
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0000ffff9f430000)
        libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000ffff9f400000)
        libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x0000ffff9f3d0000)
        libsasl2.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x0000ffff9f390000)
        libbrotlicommon.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbrotlicommon.so.1 (0x0000ffff9f350000)
        libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x0000ffff9f180000)
        libtasn1.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x0000ffff9f140000)
        libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x0000ffff9f110000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x0000ffff9f0e0000)
        libffi.so.8 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.8 (0x0000ffff9f0b0000)
root@74c0362a3530:/#


These are the contents of main.c
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return 0;
}


What OS release/version?

Do you get a successful link if you use the shared library version of libcurl?

Is it possible that you don't have the development packages for all the library dependencies installed?

@AndrewHenle Ubuntu nobel

@Philippe, generally you do need dev packages for linking to shared libraries.  But if you can successfully build an all-shared version then evidently you have them.

@JohnBollinger It was indeed the missing shared libraries. Now I really wonder, which actual files you need to dynamically link a package that were missing

@Philippe, you need a library (or a symlink) whose name has the form libfoo.so.  Note that the dynamic dependencies are on names of the form libfoo.so.version, which is not the same.  Reading the former to find the correct form for the latter is one of the activities performed in the build-time link step.  Commonly, the actual library file has the versioned name, and the unversioned one is a symlink to it.  In that case, the unversioned one is not needed at runtime.

I was missing the .so symlink of the shared library, which for some reason is only shipped with the complementary -dev package:
E.g.:
root@74c0362a3530:/# dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.*
libbrotli-dev:arm64: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.a
libbrotli-dev:arm64: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so
libbrotli1:arm64: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1
libbrotli1:arm64: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libbrotlidec.so.1.1.0
root@74c0362a3530:/#


Note that there are no "dev versions" per se in Ubuntu.  Ubuntu -dev packages (and RedHat -devel packages) provide additional files alongside those of the main packages.  They are supplementary, not a different version.
